# Using ! on a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

I am currently using `capitalize!`:

```
user_input.capitalize!
```

But, if the input is capitalized, it returns a nil.

I know I can use the method without `!`, but it will make a copy of the object and pass that instead of changing the object.

```
user_input.capitalize
```

How can I use `!`, but have it work for all cases?

I tried to `downcase` everything, then `capitalize` but the same problem exists in some cases.

What is the best way to capitalize all entries?

This is the context:

```
The user inputs "works", "Works", "WORKS", or "WoRkS"
case 1) user_input = "works"
case 2) user_input = "Works"
case 3) user_input = "WORKS"
case 4) user_input = "WoRkS"

user_input.capitalize! (case 1,3,4 = "Works"; case 2 = nil)
```

Comment: `1.9.3p194 :001 > "WORKS".capitalize!
 => "Works"`

Comment: Right, but 1.9.3p286 :001 > "Works".capitalize!
 => nil

Comment: Please post the context of your code.

Comment: What do you mean, "capitalize all entries"? There's no `!` for "all cases", the `!` is part of the method name--you don't "use `!` on a method".

Comment: @DaveNewton I think he means that he wants it to return the capitalized string in all cases (rather than returning `nil` if the string is already capitalized).

Comment: @rbynrls You can always monkey-patch (ew) or write the method you actually want. `capitalize!` is `capitalize!`, it's written the way it's written.

Comment: @DaveNewton ok, I just wasn't sure if there is a "right" way/convention in ruby to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` methods, by convention, modify the receiver and return nil if they make no changes. The safest way to do it is to use two lines:

```
user_name.capitalize!
user_name
```

or `#tap`:

```
user_name.tap do |s|
  s.capitalize!
end
```

Although, `#tap` is overkill here.

Comment: So, given that you need to repeat `user_name`, why not just `user_name = user_name.capitalize`? That is, I think the demand to use `!` no matter what doesn't really pay here.

Comment: @Telemachus agreed, and good point, but I was just answering his core question

Comment: Fair enough, though sometimes I think the best thing to say is "Don't obsess about <whatever>, just do <the obvious thing>."

Comment: You can shorten it to `user_name.tap(&:capitalize!)`.

Answer (score 2):

If all you care about is that the input gets capitalized, use `capitalize!` and don't worry about the `nil`.

If you can't have a `nil` at a certain point in your code (for some reason), don't use `capitalize!`. Instead do this:

```
user_input = user_input.capitalize
```

At the end of the day, either way is fine, idiomatic and will get the input into the state you want it. In and of itself, a `nil` return value isn't a bad thing - although you may not always want it as a final return value.

Comment: But that just makes a copy of the object, instead of changing the actual object.  Is this the "right" way to use a method like this.  So instead of changing the object, just let it make a copy?

Comment: I'm not sure what your real problem is with either `capitalize` or `capitalize!`. The `nil` return value doesn't (necessarily) matter, if all you care about is that the variable is capitalized. On the other hand, if for some reason specific to your app, you can't have a `nil` there, then it is fine to do `x = x.mutator`. That way the return value is the mutated x, no matter what.

Comment: To put that another way around, do you really want to start writing a custom method that (1) checks if the item is capitalized and then (2) uses `capitalize` or `capitalize!` depending on the test? Is it really that important? We're talking about getting some strings in shape, right? It's already easy. Don't make it hard.

Comment: OK, got ya.  Again, this has less to do with a real world problem, and more about the "right" way of handling this in Ruby. I'm just curious to see if the Ruby community has ruled on this. Thanks.